# How to call a stored function using the MySQL Connector/Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to call a stored function from Python code. 
If I use:

```
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime

with ... as conn
  c = conn.cursor()
  func = "SELECT get_customer_balance(%s, %s)"
  customer_id = 577
  dt = datetime(2015, 6, 30, 18, 5, 30)
  result = c.execute(func, (customer_id, dt))
  val = result.fetchone()
```

But `result.fetchone()` call fails because the result is `None`.
I tried also driver's `callproc` method used for stored procedures, but it fails as it does not recognize `get_customer_balance` (since it is a stored function).
I can't find any information about this. Would really appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a python expert, just want to ask, how did you construct your function also your connection string? is it tested and running?

Comment: Yes, it run. I had a separate function which created the connection object to the "sakila" database (a demo database from the MySQL site), but I didn't show it here for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, my oversight... calling fetchone() on the result instead of the cursor.
It actually works:

```
val = c.fetchone()
```